# How do you wash your water repellent apparel (DWR)?

Tags: clothing

Although some have said that Tide was acceptable, I've read that any kind of detergent is unsuitable for washing water repellent / breathable material.  Apparently detergent leaves behind a residue that coats the DWR, rendering it useless.

My research ultimately led me to try Dri-pak soap flakes, made in the UK and resold through a distributor in the US.  Results thus far have been promising.  The DWR held up after the wash, and the soap lifted all of the dirt/stains.
Dri-pak is a much cheaper alternative to Nikwax Tech Wash -- about 4 times cheaper per unit washed.

So, how do you wash your DWR apparel and have you tried Dripak?

Comment: This seems an awful lot like spam. I think it would be a better question if you removed all mention of that product

Comment: Kevin must be sponsored by Tide. Removing all mentions of the competition.

Comment: fwiw, basic description of DWR if you are not familiar: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durable_water_repellent

Comment: This wasn't spam and my post didn't require moderating.  Any recommendation by anyone can be considered advertising.  I mentioned 3 products- - Tide, Nikwax, and Dripak.  See what admin Kevin did?

Comment: I agree that that extend of moderation shouldn't have happend - should be nothing bad about discussing specific brands or products. Dowwie, do know stackexchange sites are community moderated, and discussion around that is encouraged.

Answer (score 3):

I use the following video as a guide:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I4N6ZuKTZ_c

Basically:

- Prep garment: close all main zippers, open pockets, and loosen elastics.
- Wash sweat/dirt/oils off using a performance washing liquid, using cold or warm water. Regular detergent is okay, rinse twice.
- Spray garment with a DWR reproofing spray, focusing on shoulders and other high-abrasion areas.
- Dry garment in a drier, 40 minutes on regular temperature.

They recommend Granger's wash and DWR spray. I've had really good luck with this combination.